# Angular/Ionic ng-repeat + ng-init $scope variable parameter passing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

Im trying to call a function inside ng-init using the result of ng-repeat but the only image displayed is the last image that was pass to the scope variable.

Any tips or suggestion if im doing this correctly?

Template

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="feed in feeds" ng-if=fbfeed.message ng-init='addAttachment(feed.id)'>
    <div class="list card">
        <div class="item item-body">
            <img src="{{attachment.media.image.src}}">
        </div>
    </div>
</ion-item>
```

Controller

```
$scope.addAttachment = function (postId) {
    var attachmentData = MediaManager.getAttachments( postId );
        attachmentData.then(function(result) {
        if (result.data.length) {
            $scope.attachment = result.data[0];
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the **`attachment`**  field with all the objects . so add that to the object **`feed`** .

You can pass the feed id and assign the corresponding image in the function.

**HTML**

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="feed in feeds" ng-if=fbfeed.message ng-init='addAttachment(feed)'>
    <div class="list card">
        <div class="item item-body">
            <img src="{{feed.attachment.media.image.src}}">
        </div>
    </div>
</ion-item>
```

Controller:

```
 $scope.addAttachment = function (feed) {
    var attachmentData = MediaManager.getAttachments( feed.postId );
        attachmentData.then(function(result) {
        if (result.data.length) {
            feed.attachment = result.data[0];
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Great its working thanks I did not know it can work that way.